# Are questions on what-is-this-exercise on topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Often times, you can just look up what an [inverse curl](https://www.westside-barbell.com/blogs/westside-equipment-education/equipment-education-inverse-curl) is, or how to do a [decline pushup](https://www.healthline.com/health/decline-push-up).  Sometimes though, there are weird terms like a Hail Mary lunge (sometimes used in mass/military training; it's a forward lunge done in unison to a count).  Are questions about what those are on topic?

Answer (score 2):

My opinion? Definitely yes. It's an area where people obviously do get confused, and there's generally a definitive answer, or at least a narrow enough spread that we can count one answer as most correct (occasionally, especially when there's only a partial text description or a single image, you kind of get into a "well, if he's moving down, that's a "Mahler Dip", an arm exercise, but if the focus is on contracting the glutes, you actually get a different exercise, the "Popkin Push", which targets the lower back..." situation). In my opinion, it's especially important when there are a lot of variations, the same name applies to different exercises, or several names are used for an exercise, because that's where confusion lies. I could see someone having been told to do "Romanian dead lifts" as a bodyweight exercise, and getting confused because all of the examples are with weights, not realizing they should be looking for the "single-leg Romanian dead lift" (which can also be done with weights, but is perfectly challenging as a bodyweight exercise for most people).